# Submit Form With Action="file.php" With No Reload?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm working on a form for my website. The markup for the form tag looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
```

The form sends an email to me using action="contactengine.php" with the form information when a user submits it. Because of the page layout I have, however, I can't have the page reload when a user submits the form. How can I work around this issue?

Comment: "Because of the page layout  .. " well un er fix the layout

Comment: @Machavity I have, can you explain to me how I would go about integrating it to solve this issue?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use javascript + jquery? Posting asynchronously is fairly simple with jquery.

```
$('#formid').submit(function({ //listens for form submission

    $(this).preventDefault(); //stops the submission

    $.post('actionPage.php', $(this).serialize, function(response){
       //posts the data to actionpage.php, with the form data, and then runs a function handling the response.

    });


}));
```

Comment: Sounds easy enough, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. The script looks like: http://pastebin.com/qP3tgwYy, and I got rid of the action="" on the form. I also have jQuery 1.11.1 loaded up.

Comment: It should be $('#formid') not $('formid'), fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have the server respond with a `204 No Content` response ([spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)).

> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without causing a change to the user agent's active document view

Such:

```
<?php
http_response_code(204);
exit();
```

Comment: Quentin: thanks, this looks promising. Would I add this in at the end of my contactengine.php?

Comment: I have no idea what `contactengine.php` looks like. It should go after you've processed any of the incoming data and before you output any content.