# get database data without reloading page

Tags: php

*index.php*

```
<?php 
    include_once ('Messages.php');
        $object = new Messages();
        $object->NewMessage($nick, $message); // INSERT NEW MESSAGE TO DATABASE 
        $object->ShowMessage(); // SHOWS MESSAGES FROM DATABSE


?>
Leave a message:
<form method = 'POST'>
    <textarea name='message'></textarea><br>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send'>
</form>
```

*Messages.php*

```
<?php

include_once('../login/connect.php');
class Messages {

    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Connect();
        $this->db = $this->db->DbConnect();
    }

    // INSERT NEW MESSAGE TO DATABASE
    public function NewMessage($nick, $message){
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            if(!empty($message)){           
                $nick = $_SESSION['nickname'];

                $userid = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE name=?");
                $userid->bindParam(1, $nick);
                $userid->execute();

                foreach($userid as $userid1){
                    $userid = $userid1['id'];       
                }
                $st = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO bericht (message, uid) VALUES (?,?)");
                $st->bindParam(1, $message);
                $st->bindParam(2, $userid);
                $st->execute();
            } else {
                echo 'Please enter a message!';
            }
        }
    }

    //SHOW ALL NICKNAME/MESSAGE FROM DATABASE
    public function ShowMessage() {

        $st = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM bericht");
        $stt = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");


        foreach($stt as $uhu){
        foreach ($st as $bericht){

        $nicknames = $bericht['uid'];

        $nick = $this->db->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=?");
        $nick->bindParam(1, $nicknames);
        $nick->execute();

        foreach ($nick as $nick1){
            $nick = $nick1['name'];
            $image = $uhu['foto'];

            $a = $this->db->prepare("SELECT users FROM users WHERE name=?");
            $a->bindParam(1, $nick);
            $a->execute();

            foreach($a as $b){
            $image = $b['foto'];
            }

            echo "<b>". $nick . ": </b>";
            echo $bericht['message'].'<br>';
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

http://pastebin.com/BPWjXpt1 // MESSAGES.PHP THE CODE ABOVE

---

The messages is stored in the database.

Now every time someone posts a new message, one needs to reload the page to see the new message.

I want to know how to get the new message directly when someone post the message without refreshing to see the new message.

I tried something with AJAX but because my knowledge is limited I couldn't get anything working.

I can download a chatbox that is allready scripted by someone on the net but that's not learny for me.

I hope someone can help me with this (i don't want a AutoReloadPage() function with interval TimeOut to reload the page everytime).

Comment: Try ajax again, jQuery makes it easy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23859774/3093731

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first guess is correct, to avoid reloading the page Ajax is the way to go, There's no way around it and I strongly suggest you dive into it. Ajax can be scary to learn but it's really not that horrible.

Implementing ajax to send a new message is relatively easy.

Implementing ajax to check if a new message was posted by anyone on the server and then update the DOM for all users, that's a bit harder, you'll need to poll the server and check for changes